# How to measure the entanglement of three entangled qubits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

The entanglement of two qubits is calculated using "concurrence" and "negativity". Concurrence and negativity, however, are only used for "two" entangled qubits. Is there a way or a function to measure the entanglement of three qubits?

Comment: I don't know about concurrence and negativity. However, you can measure entanglemente from the von Neumann entropy and reduced density operators for different bipartitions of the system with three qubits.

Comment: Pure state or mixed state of three qubits?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, pure state.

Answer (score 0):

The three-tangle https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9907047 is such a measure. It is in a sense a generalization of the concurrence and has nice properties.